# Multiple condition in ngClass angularJs

Tags: angularjs

I want to change class of button according to condition. Here is code:

```
<button class="btn btn-xs" type="button" ng-class="(oppdetail.status=='approved')?'btn-success':(oppdetail.status=='pending')?'btn-warning':(oppdetail.status=='rejected')?'btn-danger':'btn-warning'">{{oppdetail.status|ucWordFilter}}</button>
```

I don't know, is the good way for ng-class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably the easiest way:

```
ng-class="{'class1':<condition1>, 'class2': <condition2>}"
```